# How to get the size of interactive viewer widget after the widget is scaled?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, interactive

How to get the size of interactive viewer widget after the widget is scaled. I am using **translate of Matrix4, which I get from my transformationController**, to go to end point of the widget(right or left) on a button touch, so want to stop at the end but interactive view is going infinite way. Any way to get the last offset or size of the canvas?

And without translate the pan and scaled is working fine with finite size.

Comment: Materix4.translate which interactive view, I have a transformationController on which  I perform the translate.

Comment: use `MatrixUtils.transformRect` then

Comment: Any way to get that scaled matrix4 size or the last offset till where I can translate?

Comment: what does `MatrixUtils.transformRect` return? does it return the same `Rect` that was used as its input parameter?

Comment: New to matrix but I have tried render object and even repaintboundary object all gives me the intial size only i.e before scaled performed.

Comment: I use the Matrix from my Interactive Viewer like Matrix4.identity and then use it as Matrix.

Comment: ok how do you call `MatrixUtils.transformRect`? what is input `rect`? if you use `Matrix4.identity` it will return the same `Rect` as input `rect`

Comment: Yes so finding easy way to get the scaled interactive view size or last offset to stop translate.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **GlobalKey** to access the size of the **SizedBox** and pass a controller to `IneractiveViewer`:

```
GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
TransformationController _controller = TransformationController();
```

Wrap your larger widget with an `InteractiveViewer.builder` and a `SizedBox`. Make sure to pass the _key to the `SizedBox`:

***Note: Do not provide any bounded height or width to `SizeBox`***

```
     InteractiveViewer.builder(
controller:_controller,
      builder: (context, quad) {
    // Replace `yourWidget` with your actual widget
        return SizedBox(key: _key, child: yourWidget); 
    
      },);
```

After the widget is built, you can access the size of the `SizedBox` using the `_key` and a `RenderBox`. You can do this in your widget's lifecycle, such as in `initState` or in a `callback` after the widget has been laid out.

```
    double? widgetWidth = 1;
double? widgetHeight = 1;
_controller.addListener(() {
  double currentScale = _controller.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Size? size = myWidgetKey.currentContext?.size;
    widgetWidth = size?.width;
    widgetHeight = size?.height;
  });
  print("Scale:$currentScale");
  print(
      'Widget Size: Width = ${(widgetWidth ?? 1) * currentScale}, Height = ${(widgetHeight ?? 1) * currentScale}');
});
```

**Here is a full code for your question.**

```
    class MyInteractiveViewerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyInteractiveViewerWidget({super.key});
  final GlobalKey myWidgetKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TransformationController _controller = TransformationController();
    double? widgetWidth = 1;
    double? widgetHeight = 1;
    _controller.addListener(() {
      double currentScale = _controller.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Size? size = myWidgetKey.currentContext?.size;
        widgetWidth = size?.width;
        widgetHeight = size?.height;
      });
      print("Scale:$currentScale");
      print(
          'Widget Size: Width = ${(widgetWidth ?? 1) * currentScale}, Height = ${(widgetHeight ?? 1) * currentScale}');
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Mehran Ullah Khan'),
      ),
      body: InteractiveViewer.builder(
        scaleEnabled: true,
        transformationController: _controller,
        builder: (context, quad) {
          return SizedBox(
            key: myWidgetKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                for (var j = 1; j < 50; j++)
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++)
                        Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                            width: 500,
                            height: 300,

                            ///get random color for container
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, i + 20, j + 30, j + 60)),
                    ],
                  )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```